# How to post to user feed through facebook graph api when he is offline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created application with publish_stream permissions, now i can post on the user wall when he is using my application, but when he is offline how can i post images or status update on his wall with graph api explorer it is giving me error.